# GoogleAnalytics 2.0b4 void GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler?

Tags: core-data, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

That what is happening when I delete NSManagedObjects from the data base.

GoogleAnalytics 2.0b4 void GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *) (GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler.m:41): Uncaught exception: CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0xe0dd380 '
libc++abi.dylib: handler threw exception

This is the latest Google Analytics SDK. 
Any idea?

Comment: Yes. Do you use NSManagedObjectContext merge method?

Comment: Yes. Is there any relationship? Thanks a lot.

Comment: GA sends 'did save' notifications and your app listen to them an tries to merge changes from that notifications to your NSManagedObjectContext. And the problem is that your NSManagedObjectContext exists in a different NSPersistentStoreCoordinator. So try isolating merge method with check for NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.